# Create a dictionary using the row number in a csv file [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file containing survey data on 60 participants. The first column is the participant's number, and for each number corresponds all the data collected from that participants. It looks something like:

Participant number: 1, Gender: Female, Level of study: Postgrad

I would like to create a dictionary where the key is the Participant Number and the value is the whole of the row with all the data, to have something like this:

{1: Female, Postgrad, American, Yes, No, No, Yes, Yes, No...} and so on. I am still a newbie and so far this is what I tried:

```
with open('surveys.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    with open('new_surveys.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            mydict = {rows[0]:rows for rows in reader}
            print(mydict)
```

But this prints something like:

{'\ufeff"': ['\ufeff"'], 'Participant/Question","1.': ['Participant/Question","1.', 'Gender'], ',2.': [',2.', 'Level', 'of', 'study'],} which does not make any sense to me at the moment...

Thank you!

Edit:

This is one complete row of data:

[One complete row of data, there's 59 more but they all look the same only difference is Yes/No or time of day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZHQF.png)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add the output of `with open('survey.csv', 'rb) as f:print(f.read(100))`?  This should let us work out how the columns are being separated.

Comment: Hi, sorry for missing this. this is the output: "Participant/Question"",""1. Gender"    
",2. Level of study"    
",3. How often visit SC"    
",4. <- it is on different rows

Comment: That doesn't look like the output of `'rb'` mode - I want to see the bytes to see _exactly_ how the _original_ file is constructed.

Comment: Sorry I totally missed the 'rb' thing, first I get a csv.error about opening the bytes, then this: b'"Participant/Question"",""1. Gender"\t\t\t\t\r\n",2. Level of study"\t\t\t\t\r\n",3. How often visit SC"\t\t\t\t\r\n",'

Comment: I think there are so many parsing problems because in my Counter dictionary I have entire "words" like this 'Yes,No,Somewhat"'

Comment: I have tried getting rid of the csv.reader error and now rb mode looks like this: b'\xef\xbb\xbf"\nParticipant/Question","1. Gender\n","2. Level of study\n","3. How often visit SC\n","4. Time of vi'

Comment: The thing is that the csv gets modified once it gets opened in Python; when I first parse it it's a normal csv with Headers and then it becomes like that: ,Participant/Question 1.Gender,,,,, etc. I tried to give it a delimiter but it doesn't seem to do the job

Comment: What is doing the modification?

Comment: I have updated my code here: https://pastebin.com/7sgxmfqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this?

```
import csv
with open('surveys.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ') 
    mydict={}
    iterreader = iter(reader)
    next(iterreader)
    for row in iterreader:
        elementsList=row[0].split("\t")
        nonEmptyElements=[]
        for element in elementsList[1:]:
            print(element)          
            if(not element.strip()==""):
                nonEmptyElements.append(element)
        valuesList=",".join(nonEmptyElements)
        mydict[elementsList[0]]=valuesList
print(mydict)
```

My CSV looks like this

```
Participant Name    Gender
1   Rupin   Male
2   Poonam  Female
3   Jeshan  Male
```

The code avoids using the first row.

My output looks like this

```
{'1': 'Rupin,Male', '2': 'Poonam,Female', '3': 'Jeshan,Male'}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. It still displays very weirdly: \n2,Male,UG,Daily,Afternoon,': 'Evening",Yes,Yes,Yes,"When,I,

Comment: I updated my answer. My CSV looks like this.  Participant Name Gender
1 Rupin Male
2 Poonam Female
3 Jeshan Male

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the way python is reading my file at this point, I have so many weird commas and it still looks like this: ',,,,,,,,,,\n1,Female,UG,Daily,Afternoon,': 'Evening",Yes,"No',

Comment: Can you update your original question with the CSV?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I updated a picture of the first row, they all look the same

Comment: Anyway it does look better with your code once I 1) instead of the escape \t I use the escape \n, and I use split(",") but it still looks like this: ,,,,,,,,,,,57,Male,UG,Weekly,Evening,No,No', ',Yes,-,Yes,No,Neutral,Agree': '' So the value seems empty and there are so many extra commas...

Comment: the commas are from empty columns.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: So you create a new list with non empty elements only, and then join those with commas. I updated my answer with this change.

Comment: It looks almost perfect now!!! The only thing is that the new rows are missing quite the majority of the data attached to them. One example being '55,Female,PG', that's the only data for that participant when in the csv the row is populated by 16 cells... Any idea of why this is happening? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Try printing the values of those rows and see if they are empty.

Comment: It makes sense to keep the extra commas, because you will never know when reading the data back, which column it belonged to.

Comment: How can I print those rows? Sorry I am a total newb... Thank you.

Comment: print(reader) or print(row) depending on what you wish to print. Print statements will help you evaluate if your program is working as expected, but you will have to use your judgement as to which part is not as expected. If i could have a copy of your CSV, i could help better.

Comment: Hi, do you have an email or social network? I can't post the full document here for obvious reasons (it contains data on participants from my Uni...). Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: put a 10-12 rows here with dummy data.

Comment: Male UG Daily Afternoon, Evening Yes Yes Yes When I am studying, a lot of interruption happens No <- that's from the CSV, the reasoning is that I want to split the csv word by word to count for each participant (so using that index) to do a sentiment analysis, also dividing by gender etc. Don't know if this is the ideal way to go at this point...Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate if you can create a new question for that.

Comment: Will do just now. Thanks!

Comment: Just posted. Thanks again Rupin!!

Answer (score 0):

From the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892405/create-a-dictionary-using-the-row-number-in-a-csv-file-python#comment104069628_58892405), we know the first 100 bytes of the raw file are:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf"\nParticipant/Question","1. Gender\n","2. Level of study\n","3. How often visit SC\n","4. Time of vi'
```

This looks like a csv export from Excel, with embedded newlines in the cells.  The initial `b'\xef\xbb\xbf'` is a byte order mark, indicating that the bytes are encoded as 'utf-8-sig'.

Based on this information, this code should create the desired dictionary:

```
with open('surveys.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
    # Advance the iterator to skip the header row
    next(reader)
    mydict = {row[0]:row for row in reader}
print(mydict)
```

Passing the 'utf-8-sig' encoding ensures that the byte-order-mark doesn't get treated as part of the data.  It's probably a good idea to set this encoding when reading and writing csv files if you are working with Excel.

Passing `dialect='excel'` to the reader tells it to use the [defaults](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/39134b374fd506c5f0f6d232e259ba48c651d88f/Lib/csv.py#L54) associated with csv files created by Excel, such as using a comma as the delimiter.

Comment: This answer may get the data into the `row_number:row` dictionary that you want.  If you want to split cells into individual words you will need to call `.split()` on each cell, perhaps use nltk's tokenizer.  If the dictionary looks wrong, leave a comment here and an example of a "bad" key/value pair.