# Removing words for using NayveBayes NLTK Classifier for survey data

Tags: python, nltk, naivebayes

I have a CSV file with survey data and I wish to perform a sentiment analysis on it.

I am using the Naive Bayes to show the most informative features but the output is not showing a meaningful insight. It outputs irrelevant words such as `level` or `of`, hence I tried to manually create a list of stop words that I want to remove but I don't think it is working properly because they are still there. There is my code:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

with open('/Users/Alessandra/Desktop/Dissertation Data/Survey Coding Inst.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    alist = []
    iterreader = iter(reader)
    next(iterreader)
    c = Counter()
    for row in iterreader:
        clean_rows = row[0].replace(",", " ").rsplit()
        clean_symbols = row[0].replace("-", "").rsplit()
        remove_words = ['of', 'Level', 'study', 'How', 'many', 'SC', '2.', '1.', '3.', '4.', '5.', '6.', '7.', '8.',
                        '9.',
                        '10.', '11.', '12.', '13.', '14.', '15.', 'Gender', 'inconvenience', 'times', 'Agree',
                        'Experience', 'Interrupted', 'Workflow', 'Unable', 'Yes', 'No', 'Statement', 'Safety',
                        'non-UCL', 'people', 'guards', 'Stronglee', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'Somewhat', 'on', 'if',
                        'too', '-', 'i', '1', '2']

        # alist.append(clean_rows)
        # alist.append(clean_symbols)
        c.update(clean_rows)
        c.update(clean_symbols)
        alist.append(c)
        word_count = Counter(c)
        mostWcommon = word_count.most_common()

    for i in alist:
        if i in remove_words:
            mostWcommon.remove(i)
        print(mostWcommon)

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in alist[0])
word_features = list(all_words)[:100]
english_stop_words = stopwords.words('english')


def remove_stop_words(corpus):
    removed_stop_words = []
    for review in corpus:
        removed_stop_words.append(' '.join([word for word in review[0].split() if word not in english_stop_words]))
    return removed_stop_words


no_stop_words = remove_stop_words(mostWcommon)


def document_features(document):
    document_words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features['contains {}'.format(word)] = (word in document_words)
    return features


featuresets = [(document_features(d), c) for (d, c) in mostWcommon]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[100:], featuresets[:100]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)

OUTPUT:
Most Informative Features
              contains i = True                3 : 2      =      1.6 : 1.0
              contains 1 = True                1 : 3      =      1.5 : 1.0
              contains i = False               2 : 3      =      1.3 : 1.0
              contains 2 = True                1 : 3      =      1.2 : 1.0
              contains - = True                2 : 1      =      1.2 : 1.0
              contains 1 = False               2 : 1      =      1.2 : 1.0
              contains 2 = False               2 : 1      =      1.1 : 1.0
              contains - = False               1 : 3      =      1.0 : 1.0
             contains 5. = False               1 : 4      =      1.0 : 1.0
       contains disagree = False               1 : 4      =      1.0 : 1.0
```

Data looks like this:

```
('Yes', 194), ('No', 173), ('agree', 61), ('Agree', 57), ('to', 48), ('UG', 47), ('Strongly', 38), ('and', 36), ('unlikely', 36), ('Female', 34), ('-', 34),....)
```

As you can see even most common is not picking up the manual removal hence displaying less meaningful data... Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are able to provide the information I requested earlier in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892405/create-a-dictionary-using-the-row-number-in-a-csv-file-python#comment104062839_58892405)?  It seems likely this problem relates to how the csv is being parsed, or how it is structured.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk